# Axioms for ordered fields

Tags: analysis, axioms, ordered-fields

If i have a set of numbers, that contains every positive number, including 0 , except the negative ones, can i claim it as an ordered field? I would say no, because you can't find an $y$ for any $x$ so that:
$$x+y=0$$

So one Axiom for fields is violated. I am not quite sure, is this conclusion correct? Are there any other axioms for ordered fields violated? I can just think of this one. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The answer may depend on the precise formulation o fthe axioms, but essentially the lack of additive inverses is the main thing missing (and of course one axiom violated is enough)

Comment: Hmm.. okay. So the axioms of ordered fields are all valid here? Just out of interest

Comment: No. The axiom of additive inverse is violated.

Comment: One can define that $(F,0,1,+,\cdot,P)$ is an ordered field if these four axioms hold: **OF1** $(F,0,1,+,\cdot)$ is a field. **OF2** $P+P\subseteq P$. **OF3** $P\cdot P\subseteq P$. **OF4** For $a\in F$ exactly one of $a\in P$, $a=0$, $\exists b\in P\colon a+b=0$ is true. - Then for $F=\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ and $0,1,+,\cdot$ as usual at least OF1 is violated. The fate of the other axioms depends on $P$ (which you didn't specify).

Comment: Yeah, right, quite obvious. i just wanted to be sure - thanks!